Redis search join two indices
I have two indices, like
idx1 parent_idx (id, name, related_uuid[])
idx2 related_objects (uuid. name)
I would like to make a query using ft.search that will join those two tables and have results structure like
id, name, related_uuid, related_name.
Is there such possibility in redis search?
Read redis search docmentation

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

SQL Joins aren't currently supported on Redis query and search today. I suggest one workaround using 2 prefixes in a single index. So you can create your index using:
FT.CREATE my_combined_index ON HASH PREFI 2 "parent:" "related:" SCHEMA related_uuid TAG uuid TAG ... <other fields>

and query them using one or both fields
FT.SEARCH my_combined_index '@related_uuid|uuid:{"<UUID>"}' DIALECT 2

